# Ruby on Rails - Setting different names for url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely new to Rails and I have a database that links to a certain page depending on the user's search but it will always give me the id.

For example if a user searches, I will get, "localhost:3000/fruit/1" instead of "localhost:3000/fruit/apple". Does anyone know how to switch the url from an id to name?

Comment: You could just use a gem like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a 'to_param' method in the model you are generating a link for, e.g.

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord:Base
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you need to change the find for the show action to find by the attribute you are using in your 'to_param' method, e.g.

```
@fruit = Fruit.find_by(name: params[:id])
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-to_param for additional details